# Basics - Solvers for MDA Groups

Tags: openmdao

I am confused about the solvers that are connected to the multidisciplinary  groups as in [sellar problem](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.0.0/basic_guide/sellar.html).

What matrix are they essentially constructing? What are they converging to ? 
It is probable that I am missing something very obvious. Is there literature on this.

Answer (score 1):

In the particular tutorial that you are referencing, the nonlinear solver is [NonlinearBlockGS](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.4.0/features/building_blocks/solvers/nonlinear/nonlinear_block_gs.html). This solver doesn't need to construct any matrices of partial derivatives in order to converge its model. It simply runs the components iteratively, passing data between them after each on executes, until the model converges. Its equivalent to a fixed point iteration. If you used a gradient free optimizer with this solver, you would not need to provide OpenMDAO any partial derivatives or even call declare partials.

However, your question about `what matrix are they essentially constructing` implies that you are thinking of a [NewtonSolver](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.4.0/features/building_blocks/solvers/nonlinear/newton.html), which does indeed form a linear system to solve for state variable updates at each step. If you used a NewtonSolver on the sellar problem then the newton update equation would be

[image: Newton update linear system]

This is just the normal formula for a newton update, with the specific variables labeled from the sellar problem. In the example you cited, the nonlinear solver has been added specifically to the `cycle` group, which contains only y1 and y2 as output variables from the child components. So the newton update partial derivative Jacobian is a 2x2.

In OpenMDAO solvers can be added to different parts of the hierarchy. In this case, if the NewtonSolver has been added to the root group (instead of the lower down `cycle` group), then the Newton update system would be of size 8x8, since there are 8 different outputs variables from the components in the root group. These 8 variables are:

- x (size 1)
- z (size 2)
- y_1 (size 1)
- y_2 (size 1)
- obj (size 1)
- con1 (size 1)
- con2 (size 1)

The presence of the newton solver, regardless of what kind of optimizer you used (gradient based or gradient free) would mean that you did need derivatives. So you would need to call decalre_partials and either set `method='fd'` or provide analytic derivatives.

Comment: it is clearer thank you.some questions
1- if we used a gradient-free optimizer and  NonlinearBlockGS we dont need to declare_partials?
2- But if we used gradient-free optimizer and Newton solver we would need  to declare_partials and the necessary information will be taken from there right?
3- I have trouble understanding the newton solver and the associated linear solvers. I will look into it more. Is the above matrix being solved by the linear solvers every iteration and attempted to converge.

Comment: 4- The way i see it the newton solver matrix is included in total derivative matrix shown at the end of this page http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.4.0/theory_manual/total_derivs/total_derivs_theory.html
5- Why do we call it a solver if it essentially all it does is to evaluated the components x amount of time or to certain tolerance

Comment: I updated my above answer to be a bit more clear about the need for analytic derivatives. There are lots of good online resources about multi-dimensional newton's method (you can also search netwon-raphson method) to help you better understand the algorithm. 

As for why its called a "solver", It is because regardless of which algorithm you chose (Gauss-Seidel or Newton) the algorithm you're applying is solving for the roots of the system of equations

Comment: I think this is my question.  What is the the system of equations  built for a fixed point iteration, if all it does is to take output and feed it into the next component until it is converged. Roots of what system.